# Using Lambda Expressions to help in MVC razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, lambda

Update : I am only looking for hint on how to implement **IsHighlighted** method

I have following type of code repeated:

```
<div class="@GetCssClass(Model.IsProperty1Highlighted)">@Model.Property1
<div class="@GetCssClass(Model.IsProperty2Highlighted)">@Model.Property2
<div class="@GetCssClass(Model.IsProperty3Highlighted)">@Model.Property3
```

Also having a `IsPropertyXHighlighted` property for each X is too ugly, It would be nice if I had a method to do something like this:

```
<div class="@GetCssClass(Model.IsHighlighted(Model => Model.Property1))">@Model.Property1
<div class="@GetCssClass(Model.IsHighlighted(Model => Model.Property2))">@Model.Property2
<div class="@GetCssClass(Model.IsHighlighted(Model => Model.Property3))">@Model.Property3
```

I think this is doable with expressions but I do not how. Any hints on how to do this or a cleaner way achieving a similar result?

For example :  Lets say Proprty1 needs to be highlighted , because it is a datetime and it is Thursday, Property2 Needs to be highlighted because it is Boolean and false, Property 3 is integer and when it is even needs to be highlighted

Comment: What kind of return type from `@Model.IsHighlighted` you want? From your Razor context it should return a string for setting certain CSS class, however `Is` prefix on method name usually indicates boolean as return type.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto : Boolean would be fine, I can always wrap that in another function that returns a string or whatever.

Comment: Basically you can have method(s) inside model class, and `@Model.IsHighlighted(Model.Property1)` is possible when your model attached on view with `@model CustomModel`. IMHO, I prefer String to boolean as return type for this context, because it directly give CSS class name.

Comment: Another thing to clarify: What `IsHighlighted` method supposed to work with? I know that it will return certain CSS class for your div tags to give certain formatting effect but I don't know what process that lies behind it. FYI, the lambda expressions usually processed inside a model method, not on view.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto : Lets say Proprty1 needs to be highlighted , because it is a datetime and it is Thursday, Property2 Needs to be highlighted because it is Boolean and false, Property 3 is integer and when it is even needs to be highlighted

Comment: @Arjang what you have specified is doable and syntactically correct. Have you tried it in your code? If you want a much cleaner way or few lines of code, put your properties inside an array and implement a loop in your razor

Comment: @desperado : Not sure how I start, do you know of any samples/code or keywords I can search?

Comment: the second section you specified is already correct :)

Comment: @Desperado : How Do I implement this? What does method signature and a implementation for one property look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume your first bit looks like so:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString GetHighlightClass(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool shouldHighlight)
    {
        return shouldHighlight ? MvcHtmlString.Create("highlight") : null;
    }
}
```

If the rules for when something should be highlighted are fixed, you might have another static class:

```
public class HighlightHelper
{
    public static bool IsHighlighted(object obj)
    {
        bool shouldHighlight = false;

        if(obj is DateTime)
        {
            var date = (DateTIme)obj;
            shouldHighlight = date != null && date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday;
        }
        else if(obj is int)
        {
            var number = (int)obj;
            shouldHighlight = number % 2 == 0;
        }
        // et cetera...

        return shouldHighlight;   
    }
}
```

You would then be able to use something similar to your second guess:

```
<div class="@Html.GetHighlightClass(HighlightHelper.IsHighlighted(Model.Property1))">@Model.Property1</div>
```

You might be able to clean that up a little by moving the IsHighlighted check inside the HtmlHelper:

```
public static IHtmlString GetHighlightClass(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object obj)
{
    bool shouldHighlight = HighlightHelper.IsHighlighted(obj);
    return shouldHighlight ? MvcHtmlString.Create("highlight") : null;
}
```

And then your view might have this:

```
<div class="@Html.GetHighlightClass(Model.Property1)">@Model.Property1</div>
```

And, just to show it works, some tests:

```
using System;

using FluentAssertions;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace YourNamespace.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class HighlightHelperTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void HighlightHelper_Int_Tests()
        {
            bool shouldHighlight = false;

            shouldHighlight = HighlightHelper.IsHighlighted(3);
            shouldHighlight.Should().BeFalse();

            shouldHighlight = HighlightHelper.IsHighlighted(14);
            shouldHighlight.Should().BeTrue();
        }

        [Test]
        public void HighlightHelper_DateTime_Tests()
        {
            bool shouldHighlight = false;

            shouldHighlight = HighlightHelper.IsHighlighted(new DateTime(2016, 7, 13));
            shouldHighlight.Should().BeFalse();

            shouldHighlight = HighlightHelper.IsHighlighted(new DateTime(2016, 7, 14));
            shouldHighlight.Should().BeTrue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the rules are not fixed, I tried to keep it simple, the rules involve another object in the model, there are two complex objects in the model and their relationships needs to be checked. I can not use object as a parameter for what I need. Thank you for your answer